# How to get values from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, println

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class clsWarehouse {

private static int iChoice;
private int iItemID;
private String strItemName;
private String strItemDescription;
private int iItemPrice;
private String strSize;
private String strSex;


public clsWarehouse (int id, String name, String description, int price, String size, String sex){
    iItemID = id;
    strItemName = name;
    strItemDescription = description;
    iItemPrice = price;
    strSize = size;
    strSex = sex;   
}

public ArrayList <clsWarehouse> AllItems;
    public clsWarehouse(){
        AllItems = new ArrayList <clsWarehouse>();  
        AllItems.add(new clsWarehouse(3, "T-Shirt", "Male T-Shirt", 30, "15", "Male"));
        System.out.println(AllItems);
    }

public static void main(String[] args){
    clsWarehouse c = new clsWarehouse();
    }
}
 }
```

Hello,
I want to get the values stored in the ArrayList AllItems but all i get is the memory location [clsWarehouse@a83b8a]. Can someone help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: use function overriding for toString()

Comment: This has nothing to do with 'using a constructor'.

Answer (score 3):

You need to override the `toString()` in your `clsWarehouse` class. The `System.out.println` internally calls the `toString()` of the object in the list. Since you do not have the `toString()` method overridden in your class, you get the below as your output.

```
getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
```

The above is the [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) implementation of the `Object` class.

**Update:-**

In your `clsWarehouse` class, add the below method.

```
public String toString(){
    return  "clsWarehouse"; //Modify this to return whatever you want to display in your sysout.
}
```

Comment: Ouch, I don't understand, Java is very new to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through the array list to get the values . Also need to convert this guy to string format using toString(). Then,

```
 for (int i=0;i<AllItems .length();i++){
 //Then get the values one by one
 }
```

Hope this helps you .

Answer (score 0):

Add this method in clsWarehouse class

```
public String toString(){
    return  "iItemID: " + iItemID +" strItemName: "+ strItemName + " strItemDescription: "+ strItemDescription +" iItemPrice  "+ iItemPrice: + " strSize: " + strSize + " strSex: "+strSex; 
}
```

Change this

```
System.out.println(AllItems);
```

to

```
for(clsWarehouse item : AllItems){
     System.out.println(item.toString());
}
```